# How to cancel spring redis session publish event

Tags: spring, session, events, publish

We use spring cloud framework,use spring redis session.
And we have 20 micro service,and start 100 pods.
When we performers test,many session is create,and many create session event publish command to redis,then 100 pods subscribe event message use 100Mbit bandwidth.But this event is not use.
How can I cancel spring session send publish event when a new session create?

when spring session create,donot send event